# Attempting to create ASP.Net Core Identity data in an existing table with existing user records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a new ASP.Net Core website that uses an existing database, to which 
I have added ASP.Net Core Identity for user management.

Since there is an existing user table, I simply added the  which I have properly added the ASP.Net identity columns.

The additional columns in the existing table are in my IdentityUser-derived class.  The site logic works well when I create new users, as well as logging in, logging out, and the like.

The problem is that all of the existing 'user' records (which I will call MyUser) have blank Core Identity fields, and thus are invisible to the identity system calls.

I would like to write a utility that goes through the existing MyUser records, and if the AspIdentityId field is null, set it up as a record manageable by the Identity subsystem.

I'm essentially looking for the 'Create' call, but I can't use UserManager.

CreateAsync because this creates a new record in the table, it doesn't update an existing one.

I do have two DB contexts (IdentityDBContext and OriginalDBContext), so if there is something that allows me to generate the field data, I can then add this to the columns in the table for the associated record.

Comment: Did you follow Microsoft's guidance to migrate to the ASP.NET Core identity system? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1) This will ensure existing users have the correct ids set up and are available to the identity system. Either way, I would recommend a clean migration to the new identity tables instead of maintaining the old tables.

Comment: @Mehdi - I did go through this, I'm not really migrating from a previous system, it doesn't really currently have any identity management, have added it.  It works well with new users registering, as well as their login and logout.  It is the existing users that currently don't have any identity data populated.  Since these records are invisible to the identity logic, I can't update them.  Adding a new IdentityUser creates a new row in the table.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from running a one time manual insert of these users in the aspnetusers table. The link above has the exact insert statement to use.

Comment: The AspNetUsers table is customized with the original Users table, so all of the records are there, but the AspNet identity related columns are blank.  My needs are different than the link you provided.  Thanks though :)

Comment: if you want to update the user you have the await _userManager.UpdateAsync() method @EvConrad

Comment: @Piyush, I can't use the UpdateAsync method because since the requisite data doesn't exist in the records, when trying to find the IdentityUser record it doesn't exist.

Comment: @EvConrad I'm wondering how can you "set it up as a record manageable by the Identity subsystem" . Are you able to calculate the plaintext of your pre-existing users?

Comment: @itminus - I believe that once the record is 'recognizable' as an IdentityUser, I can call UserManager.AddPasswordAsync, which takes a plaintext pw, hashes it, then stores it in the PasswordHash column.

Comment: A simple call to `_userManager.UpdateAsync` should take care of most the the things. Your biggest issue is going to be with existing passwords. You pretty much have no choice here but to do a password reset for all your existing users.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this to work, not entirely sure why it works, seems like the AspIdentity fields are populated before they are committed.  I have only added the specific changes that were the crux of the question, the DI, setup of the contexts, etc are elsewhere in the project.

Essentially, for each 'domain' record, I create a new ApplicationUser (IdentityUser-derived) record, and add the values for the custom fields in the domain record into the ApplicationUser record.  Once this object is created, it has the necessary Asp.Net Identity fields already populated.  I then get those fields and populate them back onto the domain specific record, then I save this.  Once that is done, I re-find the record (this may not be necessary), and add the password based on the plain text password already in the domain record.

```
        var clients = new List<Client>(myService.myContext.Clients);

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser // Derived from IdentityUser
            {
                UserID = client.UserID,
                FirstName = client.FirstName,
                LastName = client.LastName,
                UserName = client.UserName,
                PhoneNumber = client.Phone,
                Email = client.Email         // Other fields omitted for brevity.
            };

            var idUser = user as IdentityUser;
            client.AspIdentityId = user.Id;
            client.ConcurrencyStamp = user.ConcurrencyStamp;
            client.NormalizedEmail = user.NormalizedEmail;
            client.NormalizedUserName = user.NormalizedUserName;
            client.PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash;
            client.SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp;

            myService.myContext.SaveChanges();

            // Can we just use the 'user' object here?
            var newUser = await myService.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(client.AspIdentityId);
            var result = await myService.UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(newUser, client.Password);
       }
```

Hope this helps someone, this was important to me to get done this way.